# Vuejs Error after updating echarts version from version-4.1.0 to version - 4.2.0-rc.2

Tags: vuejs2, echarts, vue-cli-3

I had created a project in vuejs using Vue-CLI. I have update the version of echarts from version-4.1.0 to version 4.2.0-rc.2. After updating it following error  occurs:

1. In terminal it shows error:

> "export 'default' (imported as 'echarts') was not found in 'echarts/lib/echarts'

2. and on accessing bar chart page, it shows error in console as:

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#'

Before updating the echarts package, here is my code for

> vue.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  baseUrl: process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production' ? '/' :  '/',
  transpileDependencies: [
    /\bvue-echarts\b/,
    /\bresize-detector\b/
  ],
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      //jquery plugin
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery'
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

After updating echarts version, I have replace the some lines of code with these  lines:

```
transpileDependencies: [
  /\/node_modules\/vue-echarts\//,
  /\/node_modules\/resize-detector\//
],
```

On updating these lines, I had resolved the 1st error. But in echarts page following error arises in console:

> Error in mounted hook: "Error: Component series.bar not exists. Load it first."

Here is my barchart file :

```
    <template>
      <ECharts :options="bar" style="width:100%; height:300px"></ECharts>
    </template>

    <script>
      import ECharts from "vue-echarts/components/ECharts.vue";
      import "echarts/lib/chart/bar";
      import "echarts/lib/component/title";
      import { ChartConfig } from "Constants/chart-config";

      export default {
        components: {
          ECharts
        },
        data() {
          return {
            bar: {
             tooltip: {
             trigger: "axis"
            },
            color: [ChartConfig.color.danger],
            legend: {
             data: ["Series A"]
           },
           xAxis: {
             type: "category",
             boundaryGap: true,
             data: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul"]
           },
           yAxis: {
             type: "value",
             axisLabel: {
             formatter: "{value} K"
           }
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: "Series A",
            type: "bar",
            data: [11, 11, 15, 13, 12, 13, 10]
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

How I should remove these errors. For more information please,let me know. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up with the solution, this error occurs because we cannot mix commonjs & ES modules. To solved this I updated the babel.config.js file:

```
// babel.config.js

module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ["@vue/app", {
      modules: "commonjs"
    }]
  ]
};
```

By adding above code, all your ES module code will be transpiled to commonjs and then pass to webpack for compilation.